# Multiply column major matrix linq

Tags: c#, linq, matrix

As you can see, multiply is pretty easy for row major matrices.

But in my case i have column major matrix, how can i multiply column major matrices using linq?

[image]

---

Row major matrix

```
double[][] M1 = { {a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a3, b3} };
double[] M2 = { a, b };

double[] M3 = M1.Select(inner => inner.Zip(M2, (x, y) => x*y).Sum()).ToArray();
```

---

Column major matrix

```
double[][] M1 = {{a1,a2,a3},{b1,b2,b3}};

double[] M2 = { a, b };

double[] M3 = ?;
```

These are expected results. (Sorry too lazy for writing a sample).

```
A = a1*a + b1*b;
B = a2*a + b2*b;
C = a3*a + b3*b;
```

Comment: _" If you cant help just leave"_ - I didn't downvote your question, but I can understand why someone did - there's no code or sample data with an example of what the results should be, just a big image. Many people on SO feel a responsibility to keep the "quality" high, and this question doesn't reach the bar. Lose the image, show some sample data with the expected result, and I'm sure someone will be able to help you get there. Whether you're doing forward propogations of neural networks or backwards projections of boring sales analysis is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Ok. Here is the code. What sample its matrix multiplication. What should be the result is pretty clear.

Comment: I thought the image would give the better vision. Because i was thinking about this for hours but im stucked. Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I missed groupby solution.

```
double[] M3 = M1.SelectMany(inner => inner.Select((x, i) => (x, i))
                  .GroupBy(t => t.i, t => t.x, (t, e) => 
                      e.Zip(M2, (x, y) => x * y).Sum()))
                        .ToArray();
```